# Search Bar with dropdown is not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a responsive search bar with dropdown list. I have created all components individually but getting problem in assemble them together. I want them in single line like Amazon search bar.

Here is the fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/avLkktsa/

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="search-bar-banner">
  <p style="font-size : 2em;color:white;padding-left: 100px;padding-right: 100px;">Choose The Right Course For <span class="heading"></span> </p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
       <span id="search_concept">Study Material</span> <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#contains">Online Courses</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs12">
        <input type="text" class="col-md-8 form-control" name="x" placeholder="Search term...">
      </div>
      <div class=" col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">

        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Search</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: At first I'd fix HTML (not sure if it's the only issue), there is a missing " for class attribute

Comment: but i don't think for class attribute required

Comment: " missed from class=col-md-2. check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/avLkktsa/2/

Comment: @parvez, think again. What do you think happens at space character? Will the browser think it's a space between classes or between attributes? If you want to make sure your content works in all browsers, quote the contents of all your attributes, including classes.

Comment: @parvez please refer following link http://www.bootply.com/gWOb4RcY86

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_input_groups.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div style = "padding: 100px 100px 10px;"> 
   <form class = "bs-example bs-example-form" role = "form">
      <div class = "row"  >      
         <div class = "col-lg-6">
            <div class = "input-group">           
               <div class = "input-group-btn">
                  <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" 
                     data-toggle = "dropdown">
                     DropdownMenu 
                     <span class = "caret"></span>
                  </button>            
                  <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                     <li><a href = "#">Action</a></li>
                     <li><a href = "#">Another action</a></li>
                     <li><a href = "#">Something else here</a></li>                
                     <li class = "divider"></li>
                     <li><a href = "#">Separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div><!-- /btn-group -->             
               <input type = "text" class = "form-control">
               <div class = "input-group-btn">                  
                  <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" 
                     data-toggle = "dropdown">
                    Search 
                  </button>
                  </div>            
            </div><!-- /input-group -->
         </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 --><br>        
      </div><!-- /.row -->
   </form>   
</div>
```

**Fiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/avLkktsa/17/